# Have CoffeeScript output a line as raw javascript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ios-ui-automation

Is there a way to tell CoffeeScript to just ignore a certain line and output it as is?

I want this line to be included in the resulting javascript

```
#import './blah/blah'
```

But CoffeeScript is compiling it as a comment so it ends up as

```
//import './blah/blah'
```

I need it to not do that because the script is being used for Apple's UIAutomation Instrument to drive iPhone UI. UIAutomation recognizes special #import statements but not if they are getting turned into javascript comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enclose the statement with backicks (`)

```
`#import './blah/blah'`
```

You can use any JavaScript code that way.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from adding the semicolon at the end?

Answer (score 3):

Doh, found the answer in the [coffeescript docs](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded)

```
hi = `function() {
  return [document.title, "Hello JavaScript"].join(": ");
}`
```